# How can I sort posts alphabetically in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have been following the tutorial provided by Flask. I'm trying to change things around a bit and make it fit the criterion for a glossary.

I suspect that my issue lies in this line of code in my flaskr.py file:

```
cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
```

The reason why I suspect this is because when I mess with it it breaks everything. As well, when I tried to "sort" everything it did nothing, oh and it says to order by id descending... that's mainly why.

What I tried was:

```
@app.route('/order', methods=['POST'])
def order_entry():
    entries.sort()
    return entries
```

Which is probably crude and sort of silly, but I'm particularly new to programming. I can't find any other places in my code where entries are being ordered.

I have looked for different ways to organize a dictionary alphabetically but haven't had too much luck making it work. As you can tell.

Comment: Does the `sort` method sort in-place, or does it return a new object? If it's a new object, then you need to return `entries.sort()` instead.

Comment: I guess it can only sort in-place? http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: you're missing the definition of entries, but to see what I mean, check this out: `lst = [5,3,2,1]; print lst; print list(sorted(lst)); print lst;` and then if you do  `print lst.sort();` you'll see `None` instead (replace the `;` with newlines - and you probably want to add a final `print lst` to see what happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/views/#tutorial-views) is the Flask tutorial you're following, I think your function is missing some things.  Is `entries` some sort of global variable, or did you just remove the part where it was created?  I've tried to combine your code with one of the examples from the tutorial, and added some comments.

```
@app.route('/order', methods=['POST'])
def order_entry():
    # the following line creates a 'cursor' which you need to retrieve data
    # from the database
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')

    # the following line uses that cursor ("cur"), fetches the data, 
    # turns it into a (unsorted) list of dictionaries 
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]

    # let's sort the list by the 'title' attribute now
    entries = sorted(entries, key=lambda d: d['title'])
    # or if you prefer, you could say: "entries.sort(key=lambda d:d['title']"

    # return the template with the sorted entries in
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

Now, I don't know know Flask at all, but I think this is the `gist` of what you want to do.

You may want to go through some Python tutorials (before tackling Flask), since there are a few basic concepts that, once you grasp, I think will make everything else much easier.

Comment: `lambda d: d['title']` can be simply `operator.itemgetter('title')`

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. And yes, that is the tutorial I am using. I'll go tackle some more basic python, sounds like a good idea.